# Framework manage libraries

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, libraries

I have a framework which depends on multiple third party libraries. I would like to share my framework easily. For example the user needs only my includes and add my lib to use my framework, and not all the dependencies.

I use CMake to create my libs, but I am still trying to understand how it works.

The hierarchy of the project

```
test
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── libA
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── libA.cpp
│   ├── libA.hpp
├── libB
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── libB.cpp
│   ├── libB.hpp
└── test
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── main.cpp
```

The libB depends on the libA, and I would like to add only the libB to make the project works.

The content of the main CMakeLists.txt located in **test/**:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.11)
project (C CXX)
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)

add_subdirectory("libA")
add_subdirectory("libB")
add_subdirectory("test")
```

The content of the main CMakeLists.txt located in **test/libA**:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.11)
project (A CXX)
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=c++14")
file(GLOB SOURCES "*.cpp")
add_library(A STATIC ${SOURCES})
```

The content of the main CMakeLists.txt located in **test/libB**:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.11)
project (B CXX)
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=c++14")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} "-static")

include_directories("../libA")
link_directories("../libA")
file(GLOB SOURCES "*.cpp")

add_library(B STATIC ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(B A)
```

The content of the main CMakeLists.txt located in **test/test**:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.11)
project (C CXX)
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=c++14")

include_directories(../libA)
include_directories(../libB)

link_directories(../build/libB)
link_directories(../build/libA)

add_executable(C main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(C B)
```

If I run the main CMake all works fine, the standalone is well generated.
But if I want to create only the exe by going into **test/test** and running "cmake . && make", I have an undefined reference to addL(int, int). To make it works I have to add target_link_libraries(C A) at the end of the CMakeLists. Is it normal? Is it possible to add only the main library without its dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command invocation

```
target_link_libraries(C B)
```

have **different meanings** in your use-cases.

In "all" use-case 'B' is (previously) defined as a CMake **target**, so CMake knows location of the library (`link_directories` is not used in that case), and automatically propagates all dependencies of library 'B' to executable 'C'.

In "test-only" use case there is no CMake target named 'B', so it is just transformed to linker option `-lB`. Linker searches appropriate library file under link directories (`link_directories` is needed in that case). But information about 'B' dependencies is lost, so automatic linking with A isn't performed.

---

Your project may provide a *standalone* CMake script which can be included by a user of your library. The **script should define all needed dependencies**. Common "types" of such scripts are `FindXXX.cmake` and `XXXConfig.cmake`, which can be included via [find_package(XXX)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/find_package.html) command.

Comment: If I understand correctly, for a standalone, with my static lib I need to link all the dependencies. Whereas a standalone linked to a shared library I just need the main lib.

Comment: Yes, you need explicitly link to dependencies of a *static* library. *Shared* library doesn't require this: its dependencies are loaded automatically.